# Error message on a VB Application - Impossible to run my Application installer

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I’m working on a VB project with Click once and trying to publish a new version of my code.
We’re having this error message when we run the installer:

“The archive Download Failed: ‘C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Matias2/app.publish/Application Files/Agent_1_1_0_285/Agent.exe
'C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\09O6VZGH.92N\YNZCB01K.3MG\Agent.exe' already exists’

It should not already exists because it’s a new software installation.

Comment: Running the installer on the same machine on which you just built the .exe file is troublesome.  Anti-malware dislikes that greatly, .exe files shouldn't appear from seemingly no-where.  So try disabling it to see if you can get ahead.

Comment: Hello Hans, Thanks for your feedback! I tried and still the same error..